# How to print text above a html table on every page?

Tags: html, css

When writing lines above a table in HTML the table is displayed ok on the first page but when putting this text on the next page it appears on top of the table, and the text is overlapping. This happens for all the other pages except the first one. I tried it with `@media print` but it's not working. The table is very long so it automatically gets displayed on the next pages, so when I try `@media print` it only makes the text appear on top of the table.
Also, I want the footer to be at the bottom of the page always even when the table is not full, but if I write `postion: fixed;` it makes the footer overlap with the last table row, and if I don't put `postion: fixed;` at all, if the table is not full the footer is displayed below the last row, in the middle of the page.

Here is the code:

```css
@media print {
  .header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .table-container {
    margin-top: 130px;
  }
}

.page {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
  page-break-after: always;
}

.container {
  padding: 5px;
}

.info {
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.date {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 15px;
  font-size: 13.8px;
}

.text {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.description {
  font-size: 12.8px;
}

.title,
.description {
  line-height: 0.4;
}

table {
  margin-top: 11px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

th {
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

tr:first-child {
  border-top: 0.1px solid #000000;
  height: 5px;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.4;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

table,
th,
td {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table,
.page-footer {
  line-height: 1.4;
}

tr:nth-child(26n) {
  page-break-after: always;
}

.page-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 97.3%;
  padding: 3px 1px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.page-footer>div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="info">
    <p>Text1 here<br> Text2 here<br> Text3 here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>8.6.2023</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Sorting by ID & Date</p>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h4>History and Careplans </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <p>This is an example table</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <colgroup span="1"></colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Meeting</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Nr</th>
        <th rowspan="2">T. ID</th>
        <th rowspan="2">No.</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Action/Event</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Interval</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Aids</th>
        <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup">Effort target</th>

        <th rowspan="2">Expense <br> Material</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Visa</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Execution date</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Standard [h]</th>
        <th>Species [h]</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">2004 06</td>
        <td>1.010</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Example</td>
        <td>Scope:387 cm Height: 28 m</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      ---More rows---

      <div class="page-footer">
        <div>302 T.</div>
        <div>Page 1 of 17</div>
      </div>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using this library, https://jasonday.github.io/printThis/ that might solve your problem. That library requires JQuery so you have to import it before the print library.

Comment: @Yogi I want div class="header" and table header to appear on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the position to absolute and set the top to the position you want from the top of the page, you'll get a page of a touch over 20cm

```
.page-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 97.3%;
  padding: 3px 1px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

becomes

```
.page-footer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20cm;           // this instead of a bottom attribute
  // etc. etc
```